# How to prevent hard drive from spinning down Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I had a Western Digital External 1TB drive, which I was accessing via USB. 
I decided one day, that I would prefer to mount the HDD in my case, and access it via SATA interface. So I took it apart, and the actual mounting was a breeze.

The only thing is, I think the device has some default power saving features, which means the device tends to stop spinning when idle for (x) amount of time.

This creates delays when I am accessing the HDD. Is there anyway I can turn off these power saving features for this HDD?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's (for example) a green Western Digital drive, it's going to spin down regardless, because the drive decides to turn off after a certain time.

Comment: I can confirm its the green Western Digital, nothing to prevent this?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: @JL. You can of course make sure the drive doesn't get to idle. I put the swap file on my HDD to prevent all the extra writing to my SSD, but also to make sure the HDD wouldn't spin down.

Comment: SATA drives can spin down either byt request from the host (your windows installation) or by idle timeout (on their own). **You can configure the last**. E.g. use `hdparm -s Number /dev/sdaX` where number is usually in multiples of 5 seconds. See [man hdparm](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm) or its windows equivalent.

Comment: @Jasper YOu put the swap file on an external USB drive? Lol.

Comment: @namezero Eh... no, an internal drive.

Comment: @Jasper ok sry I thought it was like in the original question an external drive!

Comment: @namezero It's not actually an external drive in the original question either. The question is about someone taking apart an external drive and then trying to use the hdd inside as an internal drive.

Comment: @Jasper Yes indeed, reading clearly helps here!

Answer (score 14):

You will need to change your power plan:

1. Go to control panel -> Power options
2. In the current power plan, click Change plan settings -> Change advanced power settings
3. Under Hard disk, set *Turn off hard disk after* to: **Never**
4. Under USB settings set *USB selective suspend setting* to: **Disabled**

Comment: Maybe not the correct answer for the OP's exact question, but this solved my spin-down problem.

Answer (score 12):

This is not always caused by power management in Windows; sometimes it is caused by the hard drive firmware. Spinning down at a period of 5 minutes or 10 is annoying if you work in Photoshop, Word or other programs and must save your work periodically. It is irritating to wait for the HDD to spinning up. It may also damage the HDD.

Solution is very simple:

- Create a batch file (with filename `spinning.bat`) in Notepad and put this script in it:

  ```
  echo a > d:\stop_spinning_down.txt
  ```

  (`d:` represents your HDD). The batch file can be put on the problematic HDD or another partition.
- Run task scheduler from Windows and create a new task to run that batch file (`.bat`) and restart that task at 5 minutes or 10 minutes. This operation writes a text file at 5 or 10 minutes and then rewrites that file over and over. The problem is that when every task is executed the `cmd` window opens, again annoying :))

We must run the batch file in hidden mode:

- Create a `.vbs` file with Notepad and put this script in it:

  ```
  Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

  WshShell.Run chr(34) & "d:\spinning.bat" & Chr(34), 0

  Set WshShell = Nothing
  ```
- Now save this file (e.g.: `spinning_hide.vbs`; note that `spinning.bat` is your batch file) at the location of the batch file and then run only the `.vbs` file with Windows task scheduler. This method writes a text file of 1k at a 5 or 10 minute interval and prevents the HDD from entering idle mode.

Comment: Change the properties of the batch file, set it to minimize at start.

Comment: Shouldn't the text file be 1 character, not 1kb (which is what I assumed you might have meant by "1k")?

Comment: Best solution without installing anything. I set it to 2 minutes to make sure. I think my WD turns into wood after 3 minutes. Also you can check if it is working or not by deleting the `.txt` file and see if the new one pops up

Answer (score 12):

It is possible to disable the spin down on ANY Western Digital hard drive on the firmware level, including the "green" drives.

[A program called idle3.exe](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=609&sid=113) is run in DOS mode, and a simple `idle3.exe /d` will go through and disable the spin down time period on any connected WD drive.

[More information](http://www.storagereview.com/how_to_stop_excessive_load_cycles_on_the_western_digital_2tb_caviar_green_wd20ears_with_wdidle3) can be found here.

Comment: how does "`ANY`" relate to this text from WD's download page: "`following hard drives: WD1000FYPS-01ZKB0, WD7500AYPS-01ZKB0, WD7501AYPS-01ZKB0.

CAUTION: Do not attempt to run this software on any hard drives other than what is listed above.`" any real-world experiment?

Comment: I have tried it on my WD Caviar Blue without success (HD wasn't damaged or similar, but it has no effect for my HD).

Answer (score 8):

To prevent HDD from spinning down on my laptop I use CrystalDiskInfo. Windows Power Management will not help, it's HDD APM settings. You have to download Standard Edition, then go to Function -> Advanced Feature -> AAM/APM Control. Select HDD and change settings for APM under APM section between Min Power and Performance. Or you can disable APM feature at all.

Comment: Two years until I've found correct answer to this problem. Thank you.

Comment: This one worked on my Seagate Spinpoint ST2000LM003. It used to spin up every 15 SECONDS and then slowly spin down which drove me INSANE. Now it's just up and running with minimal noise, and I think the spin down/up cycle would wear out the drive faster compared to it running properly now.

Answer (score 6):

I've been using the batch file approach to prevent my Western Digital external HDs from sleeping, but I wasn't a fan of the number of steps necessary to implement it—made worse since I had to do it with multiple drives.

I also wanted to fine-tune the behavior of the scripts, but I wasn't excited about spending the time to figure out how to go about it. Thankfully I ran across something that I find more convenient to implement and tweak to my individual needs.

### An Alternative to Batch Scripting

My preferred solution – that I've switched to at home and at work – is a free & open source app (Windows only) called **KeepAliveHD :** https://github.com/stsrki/keepalivehd

Like many batch file solutions it periodically writes a file to the external HD (seriously... *is there no other way* of programattically interacting with a drive to keep it awake *than by writing a file?*), but it offers the convenience of a graphical interface and adds a number of options—several of which I find very useful.

### Advantages / Benefits

- It's easy to add additional drives
  (the author claims there's no limit)
- You can customize settings *per drive*—including write intervals & enabling/disabling writes
- It's possible to disable the keep-alive writing based on inactivity
  (I leave my work computer on all the time, so my drive never slept even when I was)

You can see the source code on the project's page, which I like because it helps keep the program's behavior transparent (e.g. no hidden 'features') and I suppose it also might give non-Windows folks a starting place for creating something for their platform.

---

Anyway, I know this is an answer to an old question, but it's where I found my first (and now supplanted) solution for keeping my external HD awake just a couple of months ago, so hopefully this solution will be of use to others—whether its a first solution for them or an improved one.

Comment: Version 1.5 beta allows to disable the keep alive if the user is for X time inactive.

Answer (score 3):

If you're familiar with Linux, check out the hdparm command: http://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm (particularly the -S switch).

I've successfully turned off the spin down setting on a bunch of drives with it before. It sets the setting on the drive itself so it will persist no matter what computer you're using it with or how you format it :)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to turn this off unless the drive has some crazy firmware that completely ignores commands.  In the Power Options dialogue in Win 7, take your given plan and 'Change plan settings', then 'Change advanced power settings'.  There's an option for 'Hard disk' and 'Turn off hard disk after...'.  Set it to 0 for 'Never'.

Comment: I'd just add that I'm not 100% on the WD Green in question since they very well MIGHT have said crazy firmware, I know how hard they push the low power consumption on those. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is an improved script of [@Alexandru's](https://superuser.com/a/374929/49764/) for Windows.

EDIT: Windows 8 will not properly run scripts with spaces in their names, it keeps asking for the program to open with at each and every execution. Spaces and quotation marks have been removed from file names and version bumped to 1.01.

Save as `KeepAwake101.wsf`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package>
    <job id="keepAwake">
        <?job error="false" debug="false"?>
        <script>
            //<![CDATA[
            /*
             * Copyright 2012 XP1
             *
             * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
             * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
             * You may obtain a copy of the License at
             *
             *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
             *
             * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
             * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
             * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
             * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
             * limitations under the License.
             */

            /*jslint browser: true, vars: true, white: true, maxerr: 50, indent: 4 */
            (function (script, shell, fileSystem)
            {
                "use strict";

                var currentDirectory = fileSystem.getFolder(shell.currentDirectory);
                currentDirectory.createTextFile("empty.txt", true, false).close();

                script.quit();
            }(this.WScript, new this.ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"), new this.ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")));
            //]]>
        </script>
    </job>
</package>
```

This script creates an empty file at the root of the current directory.

Next, save this XML file as `KeepAwake101.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
    <RegistrationInfo>
        <Date>2012-01-01T00:00:01</Date>
        <Author>Administrator</Author>
    </RegistrationInfo>
    <Triggers>
        <BootTrigger>
            <Repetition>
                <Interval>PT20M</Interval>
                <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
            </Repetition>
            <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT30S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        </BootTrigger>
    </Triggers>
    <Principals>
        <Principal id="Author">
            <GroupId>Users</GroupId>
            <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
        </Principal>
    </Principals>
    <Settings>
        <IdleSettings>
            <Duration>PT10M</Duration>
            <WaitTimeout>PT1H</WaitTimeout>
            <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
            <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
        </IdleSettings>
        <MultipleInstancesPolicy>StopExisting</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
        <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
        <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
        <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
        <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
        <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
        <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <Hidden>false</Hidden>
        <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
        <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
        <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT30S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
        <Priority>7</Priority>
    </Settings>
    <Actions Context="Author">
        <Exec>
            <Command>\KeepAwake101.wsf</Command>
            <WorkingDirectory>L:\</WorkingDirectory>
        </Exec>
    </Actions>
</Task>
```

When you save the XML file, make sure that you save the file encoding as UTF-16 (labeled "Unicode" in Notepad).

On `<Command>"\KeepAwake101.wsf"</Command>`, make sure that you modify this line by adding the location of the script.

On `<WorkingDirectory>L:\</WorkingDirectory>`, you can change this line to the location of your drive.

Start > All Programs > Accessories > Right click on "Command Prompt" > Run as administrator.

Change to the directory where the XML file is located.

Import the XML as a task:

```
schtasks /create /tn "Keep Awake 1.01" /xml "KeepAwake101.xml"
```

If you want to delete the task, type:

```
schtasks /delete /tn "Keep Awake 1.01" /f
```

This task is set up to run every 20 minutes. My Western Digital Elements 2 TB (WDBAAU0020HBK) external hard drive sleeps every 30 minutes.

After you have imported the task, you can configure the interval and schedule by using the task scheduler. To open the task scheduler, in the command prompt or in a Start > Run dialog, type:

```
taskschd.msc
```

**Warning:**

Western Digital Green drives may have an aggressive IntelliPark feature that parks the head after 8 seconds of inactivity. This will cause the load/unload cycle count (LCC) to increase substantially. You can check the LCC by using software, such as Defraggler or Hard Disk Sentinel on Windows, that can read S.M.A.R.T. data.

Keeping the drive awake every 20 minutes may eventually increase the LCC over the limit. Instead of running this script, you may consider only using the drive occasionally and leaving it unplugged.

You can read more here:

http://www.sagaforce.com/~sound/wdantiparkd/

Although you could change the interval of the script to 7 seconds to prevent head parking, it doesn't sound very good.

It would be a good idea to use `wdidle3.exe` to disable the IntelliPark feature or adjust the timeout.

If you don't want to do any of that, it would be a great idea to buy a different hard drive, and use the Western Digital Green hard drive as a backup drive that you only need to turn on occasionally. Everyone loves backups.

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose of "pinging" hard drives to prevent them from spinning down, I wrote a small Windows uitility some time ago, https://github.com/MrShoenel/HDD-Ping, maybe it'll help you. This is especially helpful if you cannot use SMART to alter the timer (as in my case where I prevented a Raid-Array from spinning down).

Answer (score 1):

There's a `Group Policy` setting in Windows which disables the Non-Volatile (NV) power saving mode for hard disks which have this eco-feature. I believe the theory is that, if the HDD resume is instantaneous (or faster), then the OS can be much more aggressive in its power-down decision considerations:

> ### [Turn off the power saver mode on the hard disks](http://www.tweaklibrary.com/System/Performance-Settings/76/Turn-off-faster-boot-and-resume-time-feature/11426/)
>
> Microsoft has designed a hybrid drive that is currently supported only in Vista. This drive uses a non-volatile (NV) cache to achieve faster boot and resume. A portion of most commonly used data is copied onto the NV cache which in turn minimizes dependency on the hard drive. Eventually, this speeds up performance of your system. NV cache can also make hard disks switch to power saving mode. In this mode, the system tries to save power by aggressively spinning down the disk. However, if you do not wish switching to power saving mode which may have to compromise with the performance of the system, you turn off this mode.

Anyway, I see four Group Policy settings related to "hybrid" hard disks. They can all be found in `gpedit.msc` under:

> ```
> Local Computer Policy\
>   Computer Configuration\
>     Administrative Templates\
>       System\
>         Disk NV Cache\
> ```

1. **Turn off boot and resume optimizations**

   > This policy setting turns off power save mode on the hybrid hard disks in the system.
2. **Turn off cache power mode**

   > This policy setting turns off power save mode on the hybrid hard disks in the system.
   >
   > If you enable this policy setting, the hard disks are not put into NV cache power save mode and no power savings are achieved.
   >
   > If you disable this policy setting, the hard disks are put into an NV cache power saving mode. In this mode, the system tries to save power by aggressively spinning down the disk.
   >
   > If you do not configure this policy setting, the default behavior is to allow the hybrid hard disks to be in power save mode.
3. **Turn off non-volatile cache feature**

   > This policy setting turns off all support for the non-volatile (NV) cache on all hybrid hard disks in the system. To check if you have hybrid hard disks in the system, from Device Manager, right-click the disk drive and select Properties. The NV cache can be used to optimize boot and resume by reading data from the cache while the disks are spinning up. The NV cache can also be used to reduce the power consumption of the system by keeping the disks spun down while satisfying reads and writes from the cache.
   >
   > If you enable this policy setting, the system will not manage the NV cache and will not enable NV cache power saving mode.
   >
   > If you disable this policy setting, the system will manage the NV cache on the disks if the other policy settings for the NV cache are appropriately configured.
4. **Turn off solid state mode**

   > This policy setting turns off the solid state mode for the hybrid hard disks.
   >
   > If you enable this policy setting, frequently written files such as the file system metadata and registry may not be stored in the NV cache.
   >
   > If you disable this policy setting, the system will store frequently written data into the non-volatile (NV) cache. This allows the system to exclusively run out of the NV cache and power down the disk for longer periods to save power. Note that this can cause increased wear of the NV cache.

Answer (score 0):

If your sata controller is intel, you can install a recent intel rapid storage technology driver and disable link power management to prevent your hard drives from entering low-power states.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My 2.5" WD Scorpion Blue has an 8 seconds spin down interval set by firmware. I've tried that wdidle3 solution but the value written does not persist.

But I've found a solution for Windows, which also does not persist across restarts, but still you can schedule it on a startup and wake from standby events.

The app's called [HDDScan](http://hddscan.com/), and with it you can create a .bat file with desired PM settings and bind it to aforementioned events.