# Windows 7 Lagging with multiple disks

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, lag, latency, hard-drive-cache

I have an EVGA SR2 build with two Intel Xeon X5680, 48GB ram OCZ Reaper HPC Series at 1600 MHz running on Windows 7 x64 Proffesional. My bootable hard drive is an OCZ Vertex II 120GB and I have an extra of 4x1.5TB Seagate Baracuda. I am a web-developer/designer myself so I do a heavy multitask with many apps open 24/7. Now, all my apps are installed on one of the Seagate hard drive and my important source files are on another Vertex II 60GB (6th hard drive).

When I work with my source files, if I leave the PC idle for some period of time and I get back to it, on the next save it takes 6-7 seconds to load the explorer (does that makes sense?) and during that time it shows the loading icon:

[image: Loading]

Also when I try to open my files it does the same, or open an image... Mostly this happens when I try to search something from the start button... It seems that files or not cached? I don't know to explain this.

The CPU usage is never more than 2% and the memory around 5GB out of 48GB.

Anyone had this problem before? How can I solve this? I never had any problem on any other PC in the past and the files are being saved on an SSD so I can't see why it takes so long?

Comment: I've been encountering peculiar reports during the last few months from some users about their computers running slowly similar to what you're experiencing.  I'm starting to wonder if one of the Windows Updates might be causing this, because my clients who have their automatic updates explicitly disabled are not experiencing these performance problems.

Comment: I suspect the problem is caused by the SSD. Could you test it? Also you could try installation another copy of your on one of your other disks or in your memory (using RAM drive and disk image loader/virtual machine) and see if the situation improves.

Comment: The SSD's are new. Like at this moment if I go in of my hard disks files I will get that loading again to view the files. @RandolfRichardson It's more than a month this is happening. I use another computer at work although with ONE hard drive and I have no problem at all

Comment: @billc.cn I haven't done any raid at all but with all that specs I would assume that raiding my hard drives wouldn't make a difference in this situation

Comment: No, RAID won't help here as you obviously have some problem with system drive access speeds. This could be a software problem, but could you need to rule out hardware ones first. Installing an OS outside the SSD is a most straightforward way to test my theory. If you want you can make the install inside a virtual machine and copy the disk image to the different drives to see which works better. Even new SSDs could have firmware problems that make them especially slow under certain conditions.

Comment: If this only happens after the computer is idle, it may be because the hard drives have [gone to sleep](http://superuser.com/questions/236815/how-to-prevent-hard-drive-from-spinning-down-windows-7).