# A Script/way to constantly read on an external Hard drive to prevent it from spinning down

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

Hey guys I have a problem here.

I think I got a dying 2TB seagate expansion here, it clicks when it reads something when I just plugged it in. The problem is, when I stop reading or writing from the hard drive even for 3 minutes (pausing a music,movie playback), it just fails to spin up again (it just clicks repeatedly for 15+ times before it stop clicking and my computer see it as disconnected)

I already tried turning off some power options and scheduling as suggested here: [How to prevent hard drive from spinning down Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/236815/how-to-prevent-hard-drive-from-spinning-down-windows-7) and it still spin down. Also tried to download it's software suite to change the firmware to change power options but it still spin down.

But I experience a temporary solution. When I try to seed something in a torrent file on that hard drive, it doesn't spin down and it stays detected to my PC. I can prolly just do these, but it wastes my bandwidth (got a 500gb data cap monthly)

So My question is:
**Is there a script/way to make my computer read something on the faulty ext hard drive constantly (just like utorrent) to stop it spinning down?**

I kinda don't want to use the write file script on the thread I linked because I think writing a file constantly will wear this hard drive faster than reading on it.

I just want to use the hard drive to the fullest before it dies out. Unfortunately for me, the extended 2 year warranty that I just purchased just ended a month ago so I'm kinda mad that I can't get a new one. Already Backupped the data on this drive so I'm ready for it to die any second.

Comment: First things first: Backup your data.

Comment: Stated on my last sentence ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run something like for following CMD script:

```
:again
dir x:\*.* /S > nul
::  adjust timeout 10s to your requirements!
ping -n 10 127.0.0.1 > nul
goto again
```

But this might shorten the remaining lifespan of your disk as it involves actual read operations.

Comment: will do and report back later if it works ;)

Comment: It's working, set it to 20sec. I tested it to run for 12hours and hard drive didn't disconnect