# Hard drive caches too fast?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, freeze, cache

i got a problem with my hard drives, I think ;)
Well I realized that flash videos and games are stucking/freezing for a short time. When I googled that problem I found a script changing some parameters and everythink was fine. But unfortunately I had to format my drives and reinstall Windows so I lost this script.  I don't really know what it did (I know it is not good to use something you don't know what it does ;)).

Well I just want back this script or another solution to this freezing problem. When I found the script the author additionally described the problem like this:
"The hard drives are caching too fast so the drive is idling and "shuts down". When the drive restarts to start caching again it comes to these freezings".

Well I googled for hours now and can't find this script again. Everything I found was to change energy options for hard drives hibernation (should set it to never oder 600 minutes), but this did not work.

So can you help me to fix this problem?
I use an acer aspire v3-772g with:

- intelcore i7 (2,2GHz)
- Dual Graphics (Nvidia with 4GB RAM / Intel Onboard with less RAM ;)
- 16GB RAM, 120 GB SSD (Windows installed here) and 1TB HDD (Games and Documents).
- Windows 8.1

I hope you got enough information. If not please feel free to ask for more.
Thank you very much !!!!!!
Kind regards
j0chn

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the script you are talking about but this other question seem to provide a script to solve your problem...

[How to prevent hard drive from spinning down Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/236815/how-to-prevent-hard-drive-from-spinning-down-windows-7)

Comment: Thanks for the link. With KeepAliveHD it seems to work but in my opinion it is just a workaround. HDPARM -S unfortunately did not work. So sadly I am not satisfied with this "solution". :/