# Delay accessing my second hard disk drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, storage, delay

I have got a gaming laptop with Windows (10) installed on my SSD (128Go) and a second hard disk drive of 1To. (7200 rpm)

My SSD does not have enough space so I decided to install some softwares on my second HDD.

I disabled via power management "turn off hard disk after :" (switched it to never).

I read on the web that a trick is to access the disk often as possible in order to not let it be turned off despite power management settings.
So I installed some games on that disk (so theorically it should access game files while playing, continuously, almost..) but I still got delay to access something located in that disk.

I don't know what to do and it is very annoying.

Before Windows 10 I had Windows 8.1 and it was the same.
Before Windows 8.1 I had Windows 7 and it was the same..

Anyone has an idea ?

Thanks a lot and sorry for english mistakes.

Hellcat

Comment: The delay is normal for a HDD (especially since you're comparing it to SSD). What you can do is get a bigger RAM so Superfetch have enough storage to prefetch the game data into RAM. Bear in mind Superfetch attempt to analyze your pattern, so if you usually play certain games at certain hour, Superfetch will prefetch the files at that time, and when you play other game in unusual hour, it will experience the delay (although it shouldn't afterwards if the pattern continues)

Comment: I have got 8Go RAM, is it enough ? 
Otherwise, if I understood, I should buy more RAM and/or a bigger SSD ?

Comment: If I understand correctly the problem is not with accessing information related to the games you saved there, but some other files? If that's the case even if you have games running off this HDD they won't be accessing it all the time. There are some third party programs designed to do exactly what you need - they would access the HDD so it's won't spin down. There are some suggestions here:http://superuser.com/questions/236815/how-to-prevent-hard-drive-from-spinning-down-windows-7

Comment: Thank you i'll take a look. But no, my problem is that when I manually access a file, or any software (game or not) access a file from this second drive, I have a small delay that is annoying. (Mainly if it's a game because it freezes the game for a second or two).
This delay does not appear every time. It's like the drive is sleeping even if I disable this option in power management

Comment: I tried, via your link, KeepaliveHD which write a text file every 5 minutes on the second hard disk drive but it does not work : my disk drive still needs to wake up before accessing something inside..