# HDD keeps spinning down in Windows 8.1 - hdparm and power options already set

Tags: windows, hard-drive, laptop, windows-8.1

I have an internal secondary SATA HDD in my Laptop, Windows 8.1 constantly spins it down.

I already set "turn off hard disk after" to never in power options.

I booted debian and turned off stand by using hdparm.

But still, the HDD keeps spinning down, a problem already known in Win 8.1.

Do you have other tips on how to prevent this? I would like to keep this HDD spinning constantly.

internal SATA HDD, 1 TB, Western Digital (not USB drive)

Comment: FWIW, ATA drive settings (APM, standby timeout, write cache...) are volatile among power cycles (at least for all the drives I've ever used), so you need to look for a program in Windows which sets those for you and make it run on every boot (and you probably need to run it after suspend as well...)

Comment: The only exception I've seen is a WD My Passport. The reason its standby timeout setting is persistent among power cycles is because the state is stored in the "enclosure" and it reinforce the setting on the ATA drive behind upon power up every time.

Comment: This might help, tho it didn't help me : ( http://superuser.com/questions/236815/how-to-prevent-hard-drive-from-spinning-down-windows-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a WD DOS program, but this did not change anything.
I am using KeepAlive HD now, it creates a text file on defined HDDs even in seconds interval.

Idiotic, but works. for me