# WD passport hard drive fails after a time

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have a Western Digital passport hard drive since 4 years ago.

Recently, when I plug the external drive to my laptop, first it is detected but after some time, it is automatically unplugged.

I can't find an error with any software like *"lifeguard Diagnostic for Windows"* because during the process with the software, the drive is unplugged.

I don't know why it is happening and I would like to know the cause of this behavior.

Comment: Have you tried plugging it to a different USB-port on your computer or a different computer in general?

Comment: Does [this answer to How to prevent hard drive from spinning down Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/a/622124/272824) help?

Comment: Also try a different cable. Sounds like it may be interrupted.

Comment: I would make a back up of anything important off that drive in case it fails completely.

Comment: I'd second the others' suggestions, @lida and advise you to try using a different cable with the WD My Passport. You should also see if plugging it to a different port on your laptop will do the job. If you have access to another Windows PC/laptop, I'd suggest you check how the WD My Passport will get detected there as well. As soon as you gain access to the files on the external, make sure you back them up somewhere else. Having at least two copies of the content will save you from the headaches of data loss. Keep us posted & Good luck! :)

Comment: I agree with using a different cable. I had one acting faulty to the point I almost smashed it with a slegehammer I was pretty mad. But it was the cable in my case.