# Win 7 PC with i7 After SSD install, extremely slow "paint of green bar" on Directory open, performance issue

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, performance

I have 16G ram and 2T hard drive, then added 120G Samsung SSD as new boot C: (had shop do it) and 2 things happened.  The performance was much better for Win boot, but sometimes on opening a drive or a directory that green bar that paints on top of the box would take a minute maybe even 4 mins to slowly paint. Other times no issue at all, fast.  At the same time Search all of a sudden would miss both files and directories that were actually there.  Think the 2 are related.[Image Of Slow Green Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybmgG.png)

Anyone have same issue, whether relate to or not a SSD addition?   Any thoughts on a solution?

Took it back to shop twice, they could not figure it out, besides the fact they set directories to "Videos" for optimization and it did get considerably better when set "General Items".  But the problem does come back now and then.

Comment: I believe your picture shows that you are trying to access the hard drive disk right? You might want to check if your hard drive is spinning down after a certain amount of time and needs to spin up again when you try to access something. [Check this question to read more](http://superuser.com/questions/236815/how-to-prevent-hard-drive-from-spinning-down-windows-7) and edit in if it worked or not :)

Comment: Hi BenjaminS, thanks.   The disk is definitely up and spinning, and it can take over 3mins sometimes maybe even 10 mins, so disk can fire up much faster than that.  Think it has something to do with indexing, as Search misses things.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you got a used SSD, you need to run a TRIM. In windows 10, this is done automatically, but in windows 7, you need to get the SSD manufacturer's tools for this (which for your SSD is probably Samsung Magician and then select something like "optimize"). (save work and close programs first... I have seen it hang)

It is also possible that you have bad alignment, however unlikely. Use `wmic partition get BlockSize, StartingOffset, Name, Index` to see the offsets, and make sure they're divisible by 2048. This problem is possibly common on machines that upgraded from winxp which aligned to 63 sectors instead. And probably the shop used a tool to convert your disk that should have done this already. (to fix this, you may need to reinstall, or use special tools)

Comment: Hi Peter,  It was definitely new Samsung SSD installed by PC shop with Magician by Samsung.  Will definitely check out the other thing you mention.   The hints on this are Seach not seeing some things and Video/General items making a big difference in performance of a folder.   Will add an image of your request for wmic, as not quite sure how to read results.

Comment: Hi Peter, have attached the wmic image, in answer post, thanks

Comment: looking at your wmic output and doing modulus of each by 2048, all return 0, so they're divisible, so everything is aligned. So you could still try running the TRIM/optimize operation. And then I'm out of ideas... oh and you should post a smartctl -a report of your SSD (add it in your question)

Answer (score 0):

Peter'[WMIC Partition results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jZ4Z.png)s request for WMIC, image of results.  Never done that before so not sure what report means, here is the screen cap.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include this information in there :) then delete this answer

Answer (score 0):

It may be MSAHCI Start, Peter your suggestion led me to this article on SSD perf on Win 7, pasted in as image.  The MSAHCI Start was set to 3, I set to zero to enable AHCI mode, it was 3.  Have not seen any green bars yet, although it been just 5 mins.   Never heard of AHCI before, but the article says it speeds up SSDs.

[Screen of AHCI instructions and me doing it on my PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhSkh.png)